Use soloud crate to play sound on MacOS but panic on Soloud::default()
I am trying to use soloud(version 1.0.5) to play mp3 on MacOS 14.5, but it just panic on first line:
let sl = Soloud::default().unwrap();

There is only an Internal Error returned from default() and println! it: An internal error occured UnknownError.
I used cargo add soloud to add it as dependency. So how can I fix this on MacOS?

I am having the exact same issue, MacOS 14.5 with M1 chip. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

@gdor11 thanks! It seems that it is fine on Windows.
